# FPDF error: Some data has already been output

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Whenever I try to create a PDF using FPDF, I get the following error:

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at path:15).

When there is nothing but the PDF script in my file, it works, but I need to collect some data out of my database.

I've added `ob_clean();` to the function `Output();`, but unfortunately, it's still not working.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
include "connect.php";

$orderId = $_GET['OrderId'];
$findOrders = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM orderLines WHERE OrderId = $orderId ");
if (!$findOrders) { 
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($findOrders)){
    $article = $row['article'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];
    $price = $row['price'];
}

require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Can't help you without seeing the code in question except to say, you're sending output to the browser, probably whitespace outside of `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: I think whitespace or echo is there in your code.

Comment: Suggestion: comment out `$pdf->Ouput()`, and call the script using `curl -o test.html`. Check the file - if it is not empty (zero bytes), you have some additional output. Might even be a PHP warning somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When this error is shown, it represents that some data is being send to your browser aside of PHP file, that is, the **FPDF** sends the header to the file be a PDF,

`header('Content-Type: application/pdf');`

however you're entering some data, like a character or even a whitespace before the header specification, which leads to the error.

Two options:

1) Make `require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');` on the script's beginning. So, the header cannot be changed and there'll be not an entrance before the header's setup;

2) If you say the script works without the database search, so the error may be at the `connect.php` file. Take a look on it to ensure it doesn't send nothing to the browser (inside `<?php ?>` and outside it also!

P.S.: FPDF already does `ob_clean()` when invoked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I still have the same problem. I've looked at my connect.php which looks good and require('fpdf17/fpdf.php'); is now on top of the script. Even when I'm echoing something I get the error.

Comment: Can you edit your first post, add `connect.php` and update the FPDF script for our visualization?

Comment: <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db', 'pass'); 
if (!$link) {                                        
 die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $link); 
if (!$db_selected) { 
 die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
?>

Comment: Strange... I tested your code and worked fine here, changing `'db'` on `$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db', 'pass');` to `'username'`.